# Distinguish Navigation on Back key pressed

Tags: windows-phone-7

In a WP7 app, in `OnNavigatedTo`, how can I distinguish that the Back key was pressed on another Page of the application, or on Start Screen/in another application to navigate back to my application?

The `NavigationMode.Back` does not give me a help, it is true for both event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please a have a look on **e.IsNavigationInitiator** property. If it is *true*, navigation is *within* the *application*. If its *false*, navigation is from *background*.

More detail : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs.isnavigationinitiator(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs.isnavigationinitiator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)